# How to display the menu icon without action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create the following layout:

[image]

In my layout `main_act` I have:

```
    <!-- Tool bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Menu -->
```

And in Manifest file I have:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainAct"
            android:label="MainAct"
            android:theme="@style/MainAct" />
```

where the `"@style/MainAct"` is:

```
    <style name="MainAct" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

I want to have no bar in order to use the toolbar so I used `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` but it displays the bar anyways with the string `MainAct`. How can I display the menu icon on the background without the action bar?

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot where it says "Main Act". Also their is a hierarchy for themes where the one in the style would be at the most bottom and the one local to activity or the view will be at the top.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916663/how-to-set-actionbar-for-transaparent-and-keep-it-over-imageview - try it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>` tag and add an ImageButton on top left corner with menu icon